# How to detect a logo using camera in android?

Tags: android, image-processing, image-recognition

I'm working on an android project that requires Real time Image Recognition feature. I'm a newbie and don't have too much knowledge of image processing. I have to detect only one image by the application, that is nothing more than a logo. Logo is in the shape of circle.

Please suggest appropriate solution.
Thank you.

Comment: Detect borders, separate the objects which are not connected, calculate average points(centers), calculate mean distance from centers, calculate deviation of distances, if deviation is low enough, it should be a circle(on 2D view). May need some transforms to check for all posibilities like view angle(3D) and lighting.

Comment: Thanks sir, But I do not have a good knowledge in mathematics, Do you have any example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to use OpenCV library. It will allow you to learn your application to recognize diffrent things. For example I've made my application to recognize cars based on the size and shape of the object.

there is a lot of examples for OpenCV how to recognize a logo or similar things

Comment: Thank you so much for your response but can you please suggest me one of the examples provided by OpenCV. Because there are a lot of examples And I am trying for three days, still I did not get anything useful. Perhaps I am missing something every time. Please sir give me any example or link to implement this.

Comment: @KhanSquare but this is the best way for finding things :) Search even on youtube, find projects you're interested in and search for the code. It is easy. I've answered on the most trouble making thing :)

Comment: We know about OpenCV, Qualcomm Vuforia, AndAR, DroidAr, ARLab & Wikitude but really don't know how to implement. According to their documentation those things seem dangerous. That's why I was asking for any running example.

Comment: @KhanSquare listen it's not that I don't want to help you but computer vision is really hard topic. You need to read and analyse tutorials and make it run. With out that you won't be able to achive anything. Trust me, I've been there. Start from object recognition if you really don't want to make any research by yourself: https://sites.google.com/a/forstersfreehold.com/visible-kitteh-project/home/announcements/tutorial1objectrecognitionwithopencvandandroid-overviewofobjectrecognition

Answer (score 0):

for detection of specific object you can follow some basic techniques of object localization such as Normalized Cross-correlation in other words its also known as template matching, you have to prepare a template of your log and just use it as a convolution mask, and convolve your input image with this mask, ideally at the location of the desired object, response of convolution will quite high, so you can further fine tune the process to localize your object.

For how to use template matching in opencv you can refer to its document page http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html

**OR**

As you have mentioned in your question, that your region of interest is circular in shape, you can use some shape measures after initial segmentation of your image.